# Jquery this.height not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, height

I am setting height of a tr dynamically using jquery. The code is run on `document.ready`.
I debugged the code and saw that the height to set is coming proper (`493`) but when I assign it, to the `tr`, it is still showing `3193` while when I see `$(this)[0].style.height`, it shows `493px`. I am confused how can that be different.

Code -

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var heightToSet = $(window).height();
    $('#tr1').height(heightToSet);
});
```

Note that elements in the table are big and due to this, there is no scrollbar.

Comment: What do you expect `this` to resolve to (what element's height are you actually trying to set)?

Comment: Is this all the code that is relevant to this question?

Comment: its a tr. modified the code posted

Comment: So you're trying to set an element's height to the same height as the window? Why not just use CSS and give it `height: 100%`?

Comment: @GGG - it doesnt work on all browsers for all elements like div, etc

Comment: @Ankit it does if you give `html` and `body` a height of `100%` as well.

Comment: If you wish to set the style property for the div, use  $('#tr1').css('height',heightToSet + 'px');

Comment: I have content in my page that have static height and need to calculate the height of the rest accordingly

Comment: And my question here is .. Why are the 2 properties showing different height. I guess it should be same

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`this` refers to the `document` element in your code. You probably want to set the height of the `body` element or a descendant of the `body` element.

Look at your console for this JSFiddle, you'll see what `this` is in your event handler: http://jsfiddle.net/qwk6x/

## Update

You can change the CSS of the TD elements in your table to not show the overflow. Currently you are setting a height but it's being ignored because the content of the element makes it much lager than the set height:

CSS --

```
td {
    display     : block;
    overflow    : hidden;
    white-space : nowrap;
}​
```

JS --

```
$(function () {
    $('#tr1').children().height($(window).height());
});​
```

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qwk6x/3/

Comment: right, but _this_ is referring to document, not the window/body/elements, etc that you really want to be changing the height of

Comment: @Ankit Any chance you can post a link to the page that exhibits this behavior?

Comment: please check .. I have modified the code i blogged. Its to set height of tr with id = tr1

Comment: @Jasper-I dont have any link for that

Comment: @Ankit That code works on its own. Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qwk6x/1/. So there is probably a CSS issue or perhaps a JS error that is causing this problem.

Comment: Correct.. It works for me till the td is as small as you mentioned in the code. But when the content of that goes up, it doesnt change the height. it remains the same

Comment: @Ankit I **updated** my answer and JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qwk6x/3/. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: I tried this also.. But its not working. I dont want to trim down the height of children.. I want to show scroll. I have updated you example and now the height is 1220

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8722/discussion-between-ankit-and-jasper)

Comment: @Ankit If you want to show a scroll-bar then change `overflow:hidden` to `overflow:auto` or `overflow:scroll`. Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qwk6x/6/. Note that you can use `overflow-y` and `overflow-x` to add only vertical or horizontal scroll-bars.

Comment: tried that out .. still not working.. Is there any reason for the two property being different and showing diff values

Comment: @Ankit I explain that in the **update** to my answer. Basically if you don't tell the browser to clip the overflow, then the element will display all of its contents, no-matter what you set the height to. So play around with `overflow` until you get what you want...